# tank-like sniper mode for artillery mod?

Tags: mods, world-of-tanks

Is there any mod that lets you use a tank-like (first-person) sniper mode in artillery besides the standard "strategical map"?

Of course the "map view" is much better for hunting enemies from afar, but sometimes the enemies breach our front and one has to fight for life, one on one. You usually can deliver a single shot from behind a cover if you manage to lure the enemy there, but there are maps where that is not viable... or too late for that. If the enemy circles you, you'll be dead before you can turn, but you still stand a chance at standard tank "sniping mode" distance - but then the classic sniper mode would definitely come in handy, so that you don't overshoot a fast-moving enemy...

Comment: This would be a cheat and cheats aren't allowed to be discussed here.

Comment: @A Pale Shadow: That would be enhancement of game mechanics similar to skins that show tank vulnerability zones, or minimap overlays showing angles your turret can turn - which are expressly permitted in WOT.

Comment: No you're wrong. The mods you've mentioned are legal but a mod to give artillery a sniper mode would not be. Not all mods are legit.

Comment: @APaleShadow Legitimacy as a mod? Your meaning is ambiguous. Mods that change mechanics in any legal ways are fine here as per the FAQ. Cheats and hacks *are* allowed to be discussed here. We don't morally referee fairness, but we are bound by legal limitations, appropriate scope, and guidelines for good, answerable questions. This question may be off-topic as it sort of asks for product recommendation where a mod meets a given criteria. The question asks a yes/no existence question, not asking for examples, but any complete answers would list some and that comes back to product rec.

Comment: @skovacs1: As for "list questions"/"product recommendations" the original rationale behind them being unwelcome is not "off topic" but "poor fit for Q/A format." That means if there is a number of answers which all fit the criteria, it's impossible to choose "best answer". That is only the case, though, if there *is* a number of answers to choose from. If there exists precisely one product on market that fits the criteria, or if there is none, this problem does not exist and the question is perfectly fine. (although the asker is unable to know this a'priori, so such questions are discouraged).

Comment: @SF. Understood ("good, answerable questions"). Regardless, the category for product rec. is "Off-Topic." I only said that it "may" fit this category. It is a yes/no existence question (which are bad Q&A anyway for often being near impossible to conclusively prove in the negative). This type of question is poor when there is not exactly one product - it happens more often that there are zero or many. To improve the question, it would be better to ask for a means to address the problem you face than to specifically ask for the existence of mods as pigeonholing it this way fits product rec.

Comment: @skovacs1: I agree, mostly - this question isn't the hallmark of great questions. I know for a fact that there is a mod that does the opposite: gives normal tanks the artillery fire mode on top of sniper mode, so I expected this to be at least possible. I guess now accepting the answer is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I dont think there is such a mod. You just need to use the normal arcade-mode to hit them.